# Convert ejs snippet to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some server-side ejs templates I'm converting to jade for my node.js/express app, but there's one piece of ejs code that I"m a bit unsure of how to properly write in jade. Here's the snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.user = <%- user || 'null' %>;
</script>
```

I tried doing something like this in jade, but it's obviously wrong since user is returned as undefined.

```
script.
  window.user = user || 'null';
```

I also tried using a ternary operation, which does't give an error but also doesn't return a user.

```
script.
  window.user ? user : 'null';
```

I basically have a user object the server controller is passing to the server template. What's the proper way to handle passing objects from the controller to the view? I'm a bit of a back end development noob so I apologize if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, if user is falsy (null, undefined, empty string etc.):

```
    script(type='text/javascript').
      window.user = "#{user}" || null;
```

If you are certain not to escape the users value, which means you may be vulnerable to CSS-attacks, you may use `!{user}` instead of `#{user}`.

I have bean trying the snippet here: http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That totally worked. It didn't occur to me that you could use '#{user'}' directly within the script.